# Windows 8 store app C++ file access

Tags: c#, c++, file-io, windows-8

I'm working on a Windows 8 store app which uses C# for the GUI and C++ (as another project in the same solution, set to make a DLL) for image processing and am trying to open a `.png` image in the C++ from a path specified from the C#. This works fine when the images are located in the Apps asset folder i.e `.\\Assets\\image.png` but when I try to access an image in the Pictures library I get `E_ACCESSDENIED` in the C++ code. I have specified the Documents and Pictures library capabilities in the c# project manifest but the C++ still gets access denied. Anyone know how to give the C++ code access rights to certain folders?

e.g calling the function defined in wincodec.h, if 'filename' is somthing like "C:\Users\Name\Pictures\image0.png" hr will have the result `E_ACCESSDENIED`

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
        filename,
        NULL,
        GENERIC_READ,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand,
        &pDecoder);


}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to obtain the path, what the path is, and how you are trying to open the file?

Comment: You should use Asyn mode to open the file, there are many Windows 8 samples from MSDN to tell you how to open a image. please search the keyword CreateDecoderFromStream.

Answer (score 1):

> when I try to access an image in the Pictures library I get E_ACCESSDENIED

Yes, that's a feature. You need to declare the picturesLibrary capability in your application's manifest to be allowed access to the pictures library.

See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/a928712c-576a-4c65-b06b-6db493e3b8d9?prof=required) for more details.